# FB share buttons doesn't share correct information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, social-networking

I have site with many share buttons for each article. 
How I do that?
I create "fake" page for each article (diferent GET variable, diferent URL) with og:tags. 
The problem is that for almost all articles the buttons works fine, but for other doesn't
The URL of the page:
[ALL NEWS](http://highlight-singing.com/bg/news.php)
It works fine for all, but not for third news from top to bottom. The page of this news is:
[enter link description here](http://highlight-singing.com/bg/news.php?fb_share=537d1ab7458f0)
I see only "-" and I dont know why.
Im using diferent og tags and:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

There is no reason to not workin, because, all news are created with loop and query to DB.

Comment: I have just ran your link through Facebook's debugger and seems to work OK now, 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/
as far as I know there is a way to force Facebook to scrape your URL's

Comment: on the FB debugger is OK, but when you post is not. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Looking at the source code on http://highlight-singing.com/bg/news.php?fb_share=537d1ab7458f0 on the share button the value "537d1ab7458f0" is missing it should be http://highlight-singing.com/bg/news.php?fb_share=537d1ab7458f0

Comment: Thx a lot bro, I fix it, but know there is other bug. When you type a comment and this comment is posting to your FB. The back link there is wrong. When I click it FB says "Unfortunately can not check details Comments, because of incomplete settings."

Comment: That's great news :) I have just tested the comment box on the following page and the back link on FB worked fine. http://highlight-singing.com/bg/news.php?fb_share=537d1ab7458f0 what page was giving you the error?

Comment: Ah I see you opened another question on this problem, after taking a closer look try removing the www. from the link on the comment box and see if there is any difference?

Comment: When you make the comment, go to your profile FB page and if there you click on the link you will see this message. I don't know what to do, omg.